# In Oracle SQL, How to replicate rows based on the binary value in a column?

Tags: sql, oracle

**Problem:**

```
+------+--------+
| NAME | BINARY |
+------+--------+
| A    |   1101 |
| B    |   0011 |
+------+--------+
```

I have table with NAME and BINARY values.
I have to replicate rows, including a column for ID by considering their respective BINARY values.

In the given example, name A has BINARY value of `1101`, which means it should have 3 rows with their IDs being A-01, A-02, A-04 and no row should be added for A-03 as it is 0 in Binary value (`11’0’1`).
How to do this in Oracle SQL query? I use 11g.

**Expected Output:**

```
+------+--------+------+
| NAME | BINARY |  ID  |
+------+--------+------+
| A    |   1101 | A-01 |
| A    |   1101 | A-02 |
| A    |   1101 | A-04 |
| B    |   0011 | B-03 |
| B    |   0011 | B-04 |
+------+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a query from `dual` with a `connect by level` clause to generate a series of numbers from 1 to 4, and then (anti)join it on the table and check if the character in that position in `binary` is a `0` or a `1`:

```
SELECT name, bin, name || '-0' || lev AS id
FROM   mytable
JOIN   (SELECT     LEVEL AS lev
        FROM       dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4) ON SUBSTR(bin, lev, 1) != '0'
```

Assumptions for this query:

1. I called the column `bin` instead of `binary` since that's a reserved word. You could use `binary` and surround it by quotes if you need to.
2. I assumed the `bin` column is a `varchar`. If it isn't, just use `to_char` to convert it to a string in the query

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d9b8/8/0)**